# WooCommerce Quantity Parameter in URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am building custom WooCommerce Add to Cart buttons and I'm encountering the following problem.

The URL for the buttons are as simple as: https://mywebsite.com/shop/?add-to-cart=131&quantity=6

131 is the product ID which is dynamically pulled from the product page. However, I also want to make the quantity input dynamic. On the page I inserted a simple HTML number input field with the ID: QTY.

What I want is that when the Add to Car button is clicked, the input from the number input field is added to the URL and then of course adds the right amount of products in the cart.

Thanks in advance!